# Compair 2 columns and add a value in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are so many suggestions in here on how to solve thes problem, but I can´t find anything I can get to work.

How do I run through a DataFrame to compare the value in 2 cells from 2 different columns but on the same row, and add a value in a new column. I know that the code I wrote cannot be used since "for loop" counts on columns and not rows

```
def open_ticker_index():
    with open('pickle/' + tickerlist, "rb") as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)

    for ticker in tickers:
        df = pd.read_csv('calcuatet_daily_stock_dfs/' + ticker + '.csv')
        df = df.tail(250)

        for row in df:
            if df['Adj Close'] > df['MA3']:
                df['Adj Close > MA3'] = 1
            else:
                df['Adj Close > MA3'] = 0
```

I have also tried this, but then I cannot be allowed to create a new column

```
def open_ticker_index():
    with open('pickle/' + tickerlist, "rb") as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)

    for ticker in tickers:
        df = pd.read_csv('calcuatet_daily_stock_dfs/' + ticker + '.csv')
        df = df.tail(250)
        df['Adj Close > MA3']

        for col, row in df.iterrows():
            if (col, row["Adj Close"][1]) > (col, row["MA3"][1]):
                df['Adj Close > MA3'] = 1
            else:
                df['Adj Close > MA3'] = 0
```

have also tried, but then I cannot be allowed to create a new column

Comment: what value are you adding to the new column. what's the formula based on the match

Comment: What does your dataframe look like?

Comment: No need to use a loop. pandas can use vectorization which is much faster. Something similar to this should work: `df['Adj Close > MA3'] = df['Adj Close'] > df['MA3']`. Please, show us a sample data and expected result to get more reliable help.

Comment: What does _cannot be allowed to create a new column_ mean, exactly? This is Pandas 101, have you read the docs? Also, you should use an actual boolean value instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I dont see what is wrong with this question ...

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Do you understand what he means by _cannot be allowed to create a new column_? If so, can you explain?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar What? What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile this topic is closed for me...well done

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I think you have me confused with someone else. I just asked OP if they could clarify something in their post I didn’t understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need make a loop , using numpy is more easy do a comparison like this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
Col1,Adj,MA3
A,1,2
B,8,5
C,7,7
"""
# Here just to create a csv
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=',')


# With 2 Logical operators > <
df['Adj Close > MA3'] =np.where(df['Adj']>=df['MA3'],'1', '0')
print(df)
# With 3 Logical operators > <  =
df['Adj Close > MA3'] =np.where(df['Adj']>df['MA3'],'1', np.where(df['Adj']<df['MA3'],'0', 'equals'))
print(df)
```

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry, my mistake. I forgot to white spaces between MA and 3 in column name "MA 3" but GiovaniSalazar yours helped me a lot, now I've found out using Numpy a bit, Thangs.